# Paging a collection with LINQ

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

How do you page through a collection in LINQ given that you have a `startIndex` and a `count`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A few months back I wrote a blog post about  Fluent Interfaces and LINQ which used an Extension Method on `IQueryable<T>` and another class to provide the following natural way of paginating a LINQ collection.

```
var query = from i in ideas
            select i;
var pagedCollection = query.InPagesOf(10);
var pageOfIdeas = pagedCollection.Page(2);
```

You can get the code from the MSDN Code Gallery Page: [Pipelines, Filters, Fluent API and LINQ to SQL](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/productschallenge).

Answer (score 65):

It is very simple with the `Skip` and `Take` extension methods.

```
var query = from i in ideas
            select i;

var paggedCollection = query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count);
```

Comment: I believe that it's OK to do something like this.  He might have an answer but maybe he wants to see what other people can come up with as well.

Comment: This was originally posted during the first day of the beta period of StackOverflow, thus the 66 for the article ID.  I was testing the system, for Jeff.  Plus it seemed like useful information instead of the usual test crap that sometimes comes out of beta testing.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this a bit differently than what the others have as I had to make my own paginator, with a repeater. So I first made a collection of page numbers for the collection of items that I have:

```
// assumes that the item collection is "myItems"

int pageCount = (myItems.Count + PageSize - 1) / PageSize;

IEnumerable<int> pageRange = Enumerable.Range(1, pageCount);
   // pageRange contains [1, 2, ... , pageCount]
```

Using this I could easily partition the item collection into a collection of "pages". A page in this case is just a collection of items (`IEnumerable<Item>`). This is how you can do it using `Skip` and `Take` together with selecting the index from the `pageRange` created above:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>> pageRange
    .Select((page, index) => 
        myItems
            .Skip(index*PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize));
```

Of course you have to handle each page as an additional collection but e.g. if you're nesting repeaters then this is actually easy to handle.

---

The *one-liner TLDR* version would be this:

```
var pages = Enumerable
    .Range(0, pageCount)
    .Select((index) => myItems.Skip(index*PageSize).Take(PageSize));
```

Which can be used as this:

```
for (Enumerable<Item> page : pages) 
{
    // handle page

    for (Item item : page) 
    {
        // handle item in page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This question is somewhat old, but I wanted to post my paging algorithm that shows the whole procedure (including user interaction).

```
const int pageSize = 10;
const int count = 100;
const int startIndex = 20;

int took = 0;
bool getNextPage;
var page = ideas.Skip(startIndex);

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", (took / pageSize) + 1);
    foreach (var idea in page.Take(pageSize))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(idea);
    }

    took += pageSize;
    if (took < count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next page (y/n)?");
        char answer = Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault();
        getNextPage = default(char) != answer && 'y' == char.ToLowerInvariant(answer);

        if (getNextPage)
        {
            page = page.Skip(pageSize);
        }
    }
}
while (getNextPage && took < count);
```

However, if you are after performance, and in production code, we're all after performance, you shouldn't use LINQ's paging as shown above, but rather the underlying `IEnumerator` to implement paging yourself. As a matter of fact, it is as simple as the LINQ-algorithm shown above, but more performant:

```
const int pageSize = 10;
const int count = 100;
const int startIndex = 20;

int took = 0;
bool getNextPage = true;
using (var page = ideas.Skip(startIndex).GetEnumerator())
{
    do 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", (took / pageSize) + 1);

        int currentPageItemNo = 0;
        while (currentPageItemNo++ < pageSize && page.MoveNext())
        {
            var idea = page.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(idea);
        }

        took += pageSize;
        if (took < count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Next page (y/n)?");
            char answer = Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault();
            getNextPage = default(char) != answer && 'y' == char.ToLowerInvariant(answer);
        }
    }
    while (getNextPage && took < count);
}
```

Explanation: The downside of using `Skip()` for multiple times in a "cascading manner" is, that it will not really store the "pointer" of the iteration, where it was last skipped. - Instead the original sequence will be front-loaded with skip calls, which will lead to "consuming" the already "consumed" pages over and over again. - You can prove that yourself, when you create the sequence `ideas` so that it yields side effects. -> Even if you have skipped 10-20 and 20-30 and want to process 40+, you'll see all side effects of 10-30 being executed again, before you start iterating 40+.
The variant using `IEnumerable`'s interface directly, will instead remember the position of the end of the last logical page, so no explicit skipping is needed and side effects won't be repeated.